# unable to recognize "calico.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "apps/v1beta1"

Tags: docker, kubernetes, calico

## I receive the following error when i try to download calico.yaml files for the pod network

**unable to recognize "calico.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "apps/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "calico.yaml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"**

*here is the full output when i run "kubectl apply -f calico.yaml"*

'configmap/calico-config created
service/calico-typha created
poddisruptionbudget.policy/calico-typha created
serviceaccount/calico-node created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/felixconfigurations.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/bgppeers.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/bgpconfigurations.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/ippools.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/hostendpoints.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/clusterinformations.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/globalnetworkpolicies.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/globalnetworksets.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/networkpolicies.crd.projectcalico.org created
unable to recognize "calico.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "apps/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "calico.yaml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"'

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the latest version Kubernetes, [API versions of few resources have been changed](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/). Try converting calico.yaml to use updated API by using `kubectl convert` command to update API versions

Comment: I tried using  ' Kubectl convert ' and received Error saying that 

'kubectl convert is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version.
In order to convert, kubectl apply the object to the cluster, then kubectl get at the desired version.
unable to decode "calico.yaml": no kind "CustomResourceDefinition" is registered for version

Comment: I used the current up to date Calico.yaml and applied it and it fixed the Issue.

Download yaml files for your pod network

kubectl apply -f calico.yaml

curl https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.10/manifests/calico.yaml -O

Answer (score 3):

Confiming, getting "latest" file via command:

> wget:docs.projectcalico.org/v3.10/manifests/calico.yaml

resolved my issue.

Was following pluralsight course and it was referencing yaml file from  `"https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.3/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubernetes-datastore/calico-networking/1.7/calico.yaml"`

Which was resulting in:

```
unable to recognize "calico.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "apps/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "calico.yaml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the current up to date Calico.yaml and applied it and it fixed the Issue. Download yaml files for your pod network kubectl apply -f calico.yaml curl docs.projectcalico.org/v3.10/manifests/calico.yaml -O

Comment: v3.10 calico.yaml not work with Kubernetes v1.16 too :-(